# KimonoLabs RegEx

Tags: regex

I'm using the Kimonolabs API builder to select text which is displayed as:

```
  One Direction Lyrics
  Song Title Lyrics
```

The Regex expression tied to this is

```
 /^()(.*?)()$/
```

I need to return everything left of the word lyrics.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^(.*?)Lyrics/igm
```

With substitution `\1`

Comment: /^(.*?)Lyrics/igm errors out and is not accepted error states: Invalid CSS selector and/or Regular Expression

Comment: I figured it out: /^()(.*?)(Ly)/

Answer (score 0):

The regex `/\b([^\n]+) Lyrics/g` will return exactly what you wanted.